# Is there a way to get revert message by my client?

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, truffle-contract, revert-opcode

I have a smart contract with this simple function:

```
function addUser( string memory _username, string memory _nome, string memory _cognome, string memory _email) public  isOwner() {
    require(bytes(_username).length > 0 , "Username vuoto");
    require(bytes(_nome).length > 0 , "Nome vuoto");
    require(bytes(_cognome).length > 0 , "Cognome vuoto");
    require(bytes(_email).length > 0 , "Email vuota");
    
    if(checkUsernameExisting(_username)==0)
    {
        userCount ++;
        users[userCount] = User(userCount, _username, _nome, _cognome, _email);
        emit UserAdded(userCount, _username, _nome, _cognome, _email);
    }
    else
    {
        **revert("User already exists");**
    }

}
```

I interact correctly with its in javascript using truffle

```
...
App.partecipazioneContest = await App.contracts.PartecipazioneContest.deployed() 
...

try {
   ...
  await App.partecipazioneContest.addUser(username, nome, cognome, email);

} catch (error) {
  window.alert(error);
}
```

Is there any way to get the reason message? (in this case "User already exists").

In my catch block I get an error but I can not find the way to get the revert error message.
(emit event doesn't work).

(Update)
The error that I catch:

```
errorStatusError: Transaction: 
0x247eeddd17eccae3376aea92587fd395d46202d78bb3aa0a9d4a0b05607de7e3 exited 
with an error (status 0).
Please check that the transaction:
- satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.
- does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.
```

Comment: You should be seeing the revert-message, unless the contract function has reverted for something else. What Truffle version are you using?

Comment: @goodvibration I'm using Truffle v5.1.32 . I post the error that i get. However I am sure my function revert because on Ropsten log there is the correct message. I need to catch the same error in my client